# Hercules Mixte 5-speed hub repair spring

Tags: repair, coaster

I pulled apart a 5-speed coaster hub on a Hercules bike. It has 2 cables, one on each side. After removing a few internal parts, I came to what appeared to be a spring that was just a mangle of wire on the innermost section of the hub. I cannot find a diagram for this hub, but what I have found is that it appears to be for loading the "chain" cable. 
Any idea on where I can find a replacement part? I am in Frankfurt. [[image: wire, spring?]]
[[image: metal wire found here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxBHo.jpg)

Comment: There are a few makers of 5 speed coaster hubs with different models. Any markings to help narrow down the search?

Answer (score 1):

The most popular 5-speed hub in Germany with two cables is the first edition of the Sachs Pentasport hub, model H5111. http://scheunenfun.de/explosionszeichnung.htm#h5111 has links to information about that hub. "Teileliste" links to an explosion drawing showing the springs used and their order numbers.